# Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char0)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner in Python writing, so I would like to ask for help. I have a script that I would like to run, but I encountered an error as shown in the images below.

Here's my error:

```
C:\Users\Austinehype\binance-position-tracking-bot>python main.py
Error occurred: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
{"ok":true,"result":{"message_id":58,"from":{"id":6651358650,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"Binance","username":"Austin
te":1709987235,"text":"Error occurred for UID 2379405BC8B43DF89DFFF42609FC27A6:\nExpecting value: line 1 column 1 (c
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Austinehype\binance-position-tracking-bot\main.py", line 95, in <module>
        nickname          = json.loads(response_nickname.text)['data']['nickName']

    File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)

    File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
        obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

    File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
        raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Austinehype\binance-position-tracking-bot\main.py", line 123, in <module>
        time.sleep(60)
```

This is my main.py

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import json
import requests
import datetime
from misc import get_header, get_json
from message import telegram_send_message
from binance import get_position, get_nickname, get_markprice

# Enter BUID (Binance User ID) of targeted accounts
TARGETED_ACCOUNT_UIDs                = [
                                        "2379405BC8B43DF89DFFF42609FC27A6"]

ACCOUNT_INFO_URL_TEMPLATE           = 'https://www.binance.com/en/futures-activity/leaderboard/user?encryptedUid={}'

# modifying DataFrame, including calculating estimated entry size in USDT
def modify_data(data) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df                              = pd.DataFrame(data)
    position                        = pd.DataFrame(df['data'][0]).set_index('symbol')
    position['estimatedEntrySize']  = round((abs(position['amount']) / position['leverage']) * position['entryPrice'], 2)
    position['pnl']                 = round(position['pnl'], 2)
    position.loc[(position['amount'] > 0), 'estimatedPosition'] = 'LONG'
    position.loc[(position['amount'] < 0), 'estimatedPosition'] = 'SHORT'
    position['updateTime']          = position['updateTime'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime(*x[:-1], x[-1] // 1000))
    position['updateTime']          = position['updateTime'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    position_result                 = position[['estimatedPosition', 'leverage', 'estimatedEntrySize', 'amount',
                                                'entryPrice', 'markPrice', 'pnl', 'updateTime']]
    return position_result

previous_symbols                    = {}
previous_position_results           = {}
is_first_runs                       = {uid: True for uid in TARGETED_ACCOUNT_UIDs}

def send_new_position_message(symbol, row, nickname):
    estimated_position              = row['estimatedPosition']
    leverage                        = row['leverage']
    estimated_entry_size            = row['estimatedEntrySize']
    entry_price                     = row['entryPrice']
    pnl                             = row['pnl']
    updatetime                      = row['updateTime']
    message                         = f"[<b>{nickname}</b>]\n<b>New position opened</b>\n\n" \
                                      f"Position: <b>{symbol} {estimated_position} {leverage}X</b>\n\n" \
                                      f"Base currency - USDT\n" \
                                      f"------------------------------\n" \
                                      f"Entry Price: {entry_price}\n" \
                                      f"Est. Entry Size: {estimated_entry_size}\n" \
                                      f"PnL: {pnl}\n\n" \
                                      f"Last Update:\n{updatetime} (UTC+0)\n" \
                                      f"<a href='{ACCOUNT_INFO_URL}'><b>VIEW PROFILE ON BINANCE</b></a>"
    telegram_send_message(message)

def send_closed_position_message(symbol, row, nickname):
    estimated_position              = row['estimatedPosition']
    leverage                        = row['leverage']
    updatetime                      = row['updateTime']
    message                         = f"[<b>{nickname}</b>]\n<b>Position closed</b>\n\n" \
                                      f"Position: <b>{symbol} {estimated_position} {leverage}X</b>\n" \
                                      f"Current Price: {get_markprice(symbol)} USDT\n\n" \
                                      f"Last Update:\n{updatetime} (UTC+0)\n" \
                                      f"<a href='{ACCOUNT_INFO_URL}'><b>VIEW PROFILE ON BINANCE</b></a>"
    telegram_send_message(message)

def send_current_positions(position_result, nickname):
    if position_result.empty:
        telegram_send_message(f"[<b>{nickname}</b>]\n<b>No positions found</b>")
    else:
        telegram_send_message(f"[<b>{nickname}</b>]\n<b>Current positions:</b>")
        for symbol, row in position_result.iterrows():
            estimated_position      = row['estimatedPosition']
            leverage                = row['leverage']
            estimated_entry_size    = row['estimatedEntrySize']
            entry_price             = row['entryPrice']
            pnl                     = row['pnl']
            updatetime              = row['updateTime']
            message                 = f"Position: <b>{symbol} {estimated_position} {leverage}X</b>\n\n" \
                                      f"Base currency - USDT\n" \
                                      f"------------------------------\n" \
                                      f"Entry Price: {entry_price}\n" \
                                      f"Est. Entry Size: {estimated_entry_size}\n" \
                                      f"PnL: {pnl}\n\n" \
                                      f"Last Update:\n{updatetime} (UTC+0)\n" \
                                      f"<a href='{ACCOUNT_INFO_URL}'><b>VIEW PROFILE ON BINANCE</b></a>"
            telegram_send_message(message)

while True:
    try:
        for TARGETED_ACCOUNT_UID in TARGETED_ACCOUNT_UIDs:
            ACCOUNT_INFO_URL        = ACCOUNT_INFO_URL_TEMPLATE.format(TARGETED_ACCOUNT_UID)
            headers                 = get_header(ACCOUNT_INFO_URL)
            json_data               = get_json(TARGETED_ACCOUNT_UID)

            response_nickname       = get_nickname(headers, json_data)
            response                = get_position(headers, json_data)
            if response is not None and response_nickname is not None:
                nickname            = json.loads(response_nickname.text)['data']['nickName']
                leaderboard_data    = json.loads(response.text)
                position_result     = modify_data(leaderboard_data)

                new_symbols         = position_result.index.difference(previous_symbols.get(TARGETED_ACCOUNT_UID, pd.Index([])))
                if not is_first_runs[TARGETED_ACCOUNT_UID] and not new_symbols.empty:
                    for symbol in new_symbols:
                        send_new_position_message(symbol, position_result.loc[symbol], nickname)

                closed_symbols      = previous_symbols.get(TARGETED_ACCOUNT_UID, pd.Index([])).difference(position_result.index)
                if not is_first_runs[TARGETED_ACCOUNT_UID] and not closed_symbols.empty:
                    for symbol in closed_symbols:
                        if symbol in previous_position_results.get(TARGETED_ACCOUNT_UID, pd.DataFrame()).index:
                            send_closed_position_message(symbol, previous_position_results[TARGETED_ACCOUNT_UID].loc[symbol], nickname)

                if is_first_runs[TARGETED_ACCOUNT_UID]:
                    send_current_positions(position_result, nickname)

                previous_position_results[TARGETED_ACCOUNT_UID] = position_result.copy()
                previous_symbols[TARGETED_ACCOUNT_UID] = position_result.index.copy()
                is_first_runs[TARGETED_ACCOUNT_UID] = False
                
        time.sleep(300)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred: {e}")
        message                     = f"Error occurred for UID <b>{TARGETED_ACCOUNT_UID}</b>:\n{e}\n\n" \
                                      f"Retrying after 60s"
        telegram_send_message(message)
        time.sleep(60)
```

It seems like your script is encountering a JSON decoding error. The error message indicates that the script is expecting a JSON value but is not receiving it.

I think the issue seems to be in the line:

`nickname = json.loads(response_nickname.text)['data']['nickName']`

The error suggests that the response from the server might not contain valid JSON data, or there might be an issue with the structure of the data.

Can somebody help me please?

Thank you
Austine

Comment: Show error messages and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Comment: Rather than show all code, please attempt to minimize the code required to demonstrate the error this is what is meant by an [mre]